# Responsive design on phone shakes/wobbles. Common reasons?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive

This is more of a general question. I have a site using Bootstrap 4 that looks fine on desktop and generally fine on mobile.  However, on certain pages, the content, from the navbar to the footer, wobbles or shakes when you scroll down. It's like there is too much margin on either side of the bounds of the page.  And so it's never quite sticks in place, alway veering left or right depending on what your finger does.  I've tried to debug it, literally ripping out line by line of the offending pages and their corresponding css.  Still, it just seems to keep happening.   I was thinking maybe there was some kind of conflict with the natural margins built into the Bootstrap css, but then it should happen on every page.    It's way too much code to include here, so I was wondering if anyone had any general ideas of what I might look for to keep things in place. I should note that this problem only occurs on mobile. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:  Sigh. Okay, here's the code. I didn't want to do this because it's a lot to sift through. It's the CSS.  My apologies for it being so long. I'm at a loss.

```
    *body {
      background-color: #F4F4F4;
      background-image: url(../images/water-background.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
    }
    .gradient-line {
     margin: 25px 0;
     height: 1px;
     background: black;
      background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(white), 
    to(white), color-stop(50%, black));
    }
    .navbar {
      color: #F4F4F4;
      background-color: #a0adb7;
      height: 5em;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .navbar .active a {
      color: #F4F4F4 !important;
    }
    .navbar ul.pages {
      display: inline-block;
      color: #233237;
      height: 0.8em;
      font-family: "Abolon", "Oswald-Bold", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.45em;
  margin-top: 1.25em;
}
.navbar ul.pages li.page {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  top: 0.8em;
  color: #233237;
  display: inline;
}
.navbar ul.pages li.page a {
  color: #233237;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar ul.pages li.page a:hover {
  color: #c2bba8;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar ul.pages #nav-brand {
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  z-index: 999999;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar {
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  .navbar .active a {
    color: #F4F4F4 !important;
  }
  .navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #a0adb7;
  }
  #mobile-menu {
    background-color: #859099;
    margin-top: 4.5em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
  }
  #mobile-menu ul {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #233237;
    height: 0em;
    font-family: "Abolon", "Oswald-Bold", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #mobile-menu ul li.page {
    margin: 0;
    top: 0em;
  }
}
.navbar-toggler {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  float: right;
  outline: 0 !important;
}
.navbar-toggler .navbar-toggler:focus:active {
  outline: 0 !important;
}
.splash {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
.splash .brand-holder {
  margin-bottom: -1.5em;
}
.splash .brand-holder .welcome {
  margin-bottom: 0.75em;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-family: "Oswald-Bold", "Abolon", sans-serif;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 993px) {
  .splash .brand-holder .welcome {
    font-size: 3.5em;
  }
}
.splash .constrain-contain {
  margin-top: -2em;
}
.splash .constrain-contain .slide-container {
  display: inline;
  font-family: "Abolon";
}
.splash .constrain-contain .slide-container .slide {
  width: 350px;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  color: #c2bba8;
  text-align: justify;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}
@media (min-width: 540px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .splash .constrain-contain .slide-container .slide {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
  }
}
.splash .constrain-contain .slide-container .transform {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.splash .constrain-contain .slide-container .transform img {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.splash .constrain-contain .slide-container .transform:hover img {
  transform: translateX(-550px);
}
.splash .constrain-contain .slide-container .background,
.splash .constrain-contain .slide-container .multi {
  background-image: url(../images/headshot.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #a0adb7;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
@media (min-width: 540px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .splash .constrain-contain .slide-container {
    margin-left: -3em;
  }
}
.splash .constrain-contain .slide-container2 {
  display: inline;
  font-family: "Abolon";
}
.splash .constrain-contain .slide-container2 .slide2 {
  width: 350px;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  color: white;
  text-align: justify;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}
@media (min-width: 540px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .splash .constrain-contain .slide-container2 .slide2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
  }
}
.splash .constrain-contain .slide-container2 .transform2 {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.splash .constrain-contain .slide-container2 .transform2 img {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.splash .constrain-contain .slide-container2 .transform2:hover img {
  transform: translateX(350px);
}
.splash .constrain-contain .slide-container2 .background,
.splash .constrain-contain .slide-container2 .multi2 {
  background-image: url(../images/jess.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #a0adb7;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
@media (min-width: 540px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .splash .constrain-contain .slide-container2 {
    margin-left: 2em;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .splash {
    margin-top: 6em;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.container {
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
.container h2 {
  font-family: "Oswald-Bold";
}
.container .mini-container {
  margin-bottom: 2.8em;
}
.container .mini-container .mini-image1 {
  height: 10em;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(../images/computer-study.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #a0adb7;
}
.container .mini-container .mini-image2 {
  height: 10em;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(../images/responsive-design.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #a0adb7;
}
.container .mini-container .mini-image3 {
  height: 10em;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(../images/colors-wheel.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #a0adb7;
}
.container .mini-container p {
  font-family: "Oswald-Light";
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.15em;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .container .mini-container p {
    font-size: 1.65em;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
.container .mini-container .btn {
  background-color: #c2bba8;
  color: #233237;
  font-family: "Abolon";
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
.container .mini-container .btn:hover {
  background-color: #233237;
  color: #c2bba8;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .container .mini-container .btn {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
}
div.footer-container {
  background-color: #233237;
  clear: both;
  color: #c2bba8;
  width: 100%;
}
div.footer-container #footer-contents {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
}
div.footer-container #footer-logo {
  float: left;
  height: 15em;
  line-height: 15em;
}
div.footer-container #footer-logo img {
  color: #c2bba8;
  padding-top: .15em;
  width: 12em;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  div.footer-container #footer-logo {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
div.footer-container .footer-links ul {
  padding-top: 1.9em;
}
div.footer-container .footer-links li {
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: .3em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: "Oswald-Bold", "Abolon", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}
div.footer-container .footer-links a {
  color: #c2bba8;
}
div.footer-container .footer-links a:hover {
  color: #F4F4F4;
  text-decoration: none;
}
div.footer-container #footer-social {
  height: 15em;
  line-height: 15em;
  float: right;
}
div.footer-container #footer-social .btn {
  background-color: #c2bba8;
  color: #233237;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}
div.footer-container #footer-social .btn:hover {
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
}
div.footer-container #footer-social a {
  color: #c2bba8;
  text-decoration: none;
}
div.footer-container #footer-social a:hover {
  color: #F4F4F4;
}
div.footer-container #footer-social .fa-facebook-square {
  font-size: 5em;
}
div.footer-container #footer-social .fa-twitter-square {
  font-size: 5em;
  padding-left: .3em;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  div.footer-container #footer-social {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 0em;
    height: auto;
  }
}
div.footer-container #copyright {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -2em;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: "Abolon", "Oswald-Light", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  div.footer-container #copyright {
    margin-top: 0em;
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this usually means you have content overflowing your html element. Try adding: `html, body { overflow-x: hidden; }` and see if that helps. But this doesn't really solve the problem. Fixing the real problem is figuring out what DOM element is overflowing and fixing that element. And nobody can help you with that unless you isolate the problem and share your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using git you could do a bisect, and see when the error was introduced

Refer to the documentation on [bisect](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect)

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't aware of the bisect. Thanks for the info!